# Summarise - Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to do a very simple count using the following code:

```
Bar_data_TEST <- Bar_data %>%
  group_by(metric) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

but keep getting the above error and I have no idea why - any ideas?

Comment: Try specifying `dplyr::summarise(n = n())`

Comment: what is the type of Bar_data is it a data.frame ?

Comment: Bar_data is a data frame

Comment: @AllanCameron This worked thank you - In what cases is this needed?

Comment: @user14142459 this suggests you loaded another package after `dplyr` that also contains a function callled `summarise`. Usually this is the `plyr` package.